# Why is my merge sort code slower than insertion sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

I've been trying to make merge sort and insertion sort and comparing the time result for both of them.
And from array input size 10 to 10000 merge sort has been slower than insertion sort

this is the code for insertion sort

```
vector<int> insertion_sort(vector<int> vec)
{
    for(int i = 1 ; i <vec.size();i++)
    {
        int j = i-1;
        while(j>=0 && vec[j+1]<vec[j] )
        {
            int x = vec[j+1];
            vec[j+1] = vec[j];
            vec[j--] = x;
        }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

And this is the Merge sort code

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int> left,vector<int> right)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    vector<int> ret(left.size()+right.size());
    int it = 0;
    for(; i <left.size() && j<right.size();)
    {
        if(left[i]<right[j])
            ret[it++]=(left[i++]);
        else if(right[j]<left[i])
            ret[it++]=(right[j++]);
        else ret[it++]=(left[i++]),ret[it++]=(right[j++]);
    }
    for(;i<left.size();)
        ret[it++]=(left[i++]);
    for(;j<right.size();)
        ret[it++]=(right[j++]);
    return ret;
}
vector<int> merge_sort(vector<int> A,int start,int end)
{
    if(start >= end) 
    {
        vector<int> v(1);
        v[0]=(A[start]);
        return v;
    }
    int mid = (start+end )/ 2;
    vector<int> left = merge_sort(A,start,mid);
    vector<int> right = merge_sort(A,mid+1,end);
    return merge(left,right);
}
```

and finally this is how I call all of them and calculate time

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> rand_vec;

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0 ; i <SIZE;i++)
    {
        rand_vec.push_back(rand()%SIZE);
    }
    int t = clock();
    vector<int> merge_sorted = merge_sort(rand_vec,0,rand_vec.size()-1);
    puts("");
    printf("merge sort time = %d\n",clock() - t );


    t = clock();
    vector<int> insertion_sorted = insertion_sort(rand_vec);
    puts("");
    printf("insertion sort time = %d\n",clock() - t );
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know if I did something wrong in that code to make the time for merge sort more than the time used in insertion sort.

Thanks.

Comment: What is SIZE?  If it's small, that might be your issue.

Comment: I am more a java guy, but doesn´t passing the vector as a parameter create a copy of it (the copy constructor)? That would be heavy.

Comment: @templatetypedef I've tried SIZE from 5 to 100000 and every time merge sort takes more time

Comment: @SJuan76 I was afraid too that passing vectors might create a dilemma. at the same time I wanted to make it this time using vectors

Comment: Instead of `vector<int>`, use a `*vector<int>` (and change the rest of the code accordingly).

Comment: or even better, (const when possible) reference `vector<int>&` ;)

Comment: and by the way, use `reserve` for your vector, before using thousands of `push_back` when you know the size in advance

Comment: @lolando Thanks. That's exactly what I tried after SJuan76 said that
And it Did in fact decrease the time dramatically.

Comment: @lolando I used to have push back in all of the merge sort code .. then I replaced it with [] operator for faster access after knowing the size .. but why would I use reverse ?

Comment: `reserve`, not `reverse`. Specify the final size so the vector is not growing each few inputs.

Comment: @SJuan76 stricly speaking, `reserve` sets the capacity, not the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to summarize the answers provided so far:
- use reference (or pointer ) to avoid copying vectors:
- use `reserve` when you know the size in advance, before using thousands of `push_back` (so that you do not need to reallocate dynamically whenever the capacity is exceeded)
- you can do `const vector<int>& merge_sorted = ...` to avoid copy when returning your vector

Comment: "People sometimes worry about the cost of std::vector growing incrementally. I used to worry about that and used reserve() to optimize the growth. After measuring my code and repeatedly having trouble finding the performance benefits of reserve() in real programs, I stopped using it except where it is needed to avoid iterator invalidation (a rare case in my code). Again: measure before you optimize." -- Bjarne Stroustrup (http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#slow-containers)

Comment: I don't think reserving harms the readability or maintainability of the code. If anything it documents that the size is known beforehand. Maybe no huge benefits but you might as well do it.

Answer (score 3):

Passing vectors by reference rather than by value makes a huge difference.  On my machine with SIZE=50000, compiled with -O3, before:

```
merge sort time = 5730000

insertion sort time = 1470000
```

After:

```
merge sort time = 10000

insertion sort time = 1470000
```

I only changed two lines:

```
vector<int> merge(const vector<int> &left,const vector<int> &right)
vector<int> merge_sort(const vector<int> &A,int start,int end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mrip answer about references, keep in mind:

"Insertion sort is one of the fastest algorithms for sorting very small arrays, even faster than quicksort. The best case input is an array that is already sorted. In this case insertion sort has a linear running time. The simplest worst case input is an array sorted in reverse order."

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort is not necessarily slower than an insertion sort.
Time take by insertion sort to sort 'n' items is proportional to n squared (n*n) while the time taken by merge sort is proportional to n times log of n base 2 (n*lgn) 
So insertion sort is faster than the merge sort in some code while merge sort in others